# Can superposition states be created by thermal excitation?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, superposition, density-operator

I was wondering if pure superposition states can be created thermally. Are only energy eigenstates occupied when we provide heat or are superposition states also a part of the statistical mix of states of a system in thermal equilibrium, proportional to a weight, based on their energy expectation value ?

Is for example a superposition state $|\psi\rangle =\frac{1}{\sqrt2}(|n_1\rangle +|n_2\rangle ) $ with energy expectation value
$
\langle E\rangle_\psi = (E_1+E_2)/2 
$
found with a probability of $p_\psi = e^{\beta \langle E\rangle _\psi}/Z$ or is it not part of a thermal ensemble ?

Comment: Not that simple. start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_thermodynamics

Comment: @annav The article didn't help me. There is a small part that talks about coherence's but I  don't understand it well enough to decide whether or not it is helping in answering my question. It sounded a bit like coherence's dephase due to quantum friction, which could mean that superposition states dephase into mixtures of eigenstates but I am not confident about this, my comprehension could be wrong.

Comment: If you are really interested here is https://www.researchgate.net/publication/333865766_Introduction_to_Quantum_Thermodynamics_Lecture_Notes

Comment: as the ntroductory to the wiki link says, it is understanding classical thermodynamics from the underlying quantum mechanical level, and it is not simple, it is a research subject

Comment: @annav I don't need a comprehensive answer at research level. I was just wondering why superposition states are never mentioned when talking about canonical density operators and wondered what role they play and if there is a simple or not so simple reason why they aren't part of a thermal ensemble. I hoped that someone familiar with the topic could give some insights into this.

Comment: The handwaving anwer is that thermodynamics depends on classical mechanics to define temperature pressure etc. These have no meaning in quantum mechanics, they have to be derived and expressions shown to be equivalent. The word "thermal" has no meaning in qm.  The term superpostion has no meaning in thermodyamics. In qm an ensemble of elementary paticles theoretically can always be described by a qm wavefunction, theoretically the whole universe at the beginning of the big bang can be described by one wavefunction. Quantum thermodynamics is trying to solve questions such as you ask.

Comment: again handwaving the individual wavefunctions of quantum entities as atoms and molecules and the infrared photons  when in large numbers become incoherent, but how they relate to terms as temperature pressure etc is under studies.

Comment: @annav Interesting. When I was taught about the canonical density operator I took temperature as granted and didn't think deeply about it but now that I am giving the topic a second glance, it seems that there is more to it.

Comment: @annav I don't agree. The theory of statistical mechanics is well-suited for qm, most of the classical problems can me found as the classical limit of a quantum hamiltonian. Moreover, there are many macroscopic experiments (aka thermodynamics) that can only be explained regarding the quantum nature of the components (eg. Bose-Einstein condensate or the black-body radiation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The density matrix of a thermal state in the energy basis is diagonal. This means that
\begin{align}
\langle n_m \vert \hat{\rho}_{th} \vert n_n \rangle
&= \delta_{m,n} e^{-\beta E_m}/Z.
\end{align}

As a consequence
\begin{align}
\langle \psi \vert \hat{\rho}_{th} \vert \psi \rangle
&= \frac{1}{2}\left(\langle n_1 \vert + \langle n_2 \vert \right) \hat{\rho}_{th} \left( \vert n_1 \rangle + \vert n_2 \rangle \right) \\
&=  \frac{1}{2} ~Z^{-1} \left[e^{-\beta E_1} + e^{-\beta E_2}\right] \\
&\neq Z^{-1} e^{-\beta(E_1 + E_2)/2}.
\end{align}

We can see that although the probability attributed to that state is not what you expected, it is not zero. It is different from your expression because the Gibbs distribution tells you only about the probabilities of energy eigenstates, as
\begin{align}
\hat{\rho}_{th} &= e^{-\beta \hat{H}}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Is it somehow weird to ask about the thermal states of just two components. Many of the results of statistical mechanics (including the equation of the canonical ensemble) are derived from the $N\rightarrow \infty$ limit. For example, the theory of the equivalence between ensembles doesn't apply and you don't know if this partition function would be compatible with  Boltzmann's Entropy.

However, I don't see why these coherent states shouldn't take part in the summation for $Z$. Since, by definition, the summation of $Z$ go through all the states of the system.

Comment: That state was just a minimal example to clarify my question. I am not particularly interested in a two state system.